# Check if expection is raised with pytest

Tags: python, testing, pytest

Being quite new to exception test handling I am wondering how to check if an assertion is raised.

a.py

```
class SomeError(Exception):
    pass

class SomeClass(object):
    def __init__(self):
        ...
        raise SomeError
        ...
```

test_a.py

```
from a.a import SomeClass

def test_some_exception_raised():
    ?
```

What assertion should it be there to check if `SomeError` is raised? I am using pytest.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In order to write assertions about raised exceptions, you can use `pytest.raises` as a context manager like this:

**a.py**

```
class SomeError(Exception):
    pass

class SomeClass(object):
    def __init__(self):
        ...
        raise SomeError("some error message")
        ...
```

**test_a.py**

```
from .a import SomeClass, SomeError
import pytest

def test_some_exception_raised():
    with pytest.raises(SomeError) as excinfo:   
        obj = SomeClass()  
    
    assert 'some error message' in str(excinfo.value)
```

For more about exception assertions, [see here](http://doc.pytest.org/en/latest/assert.html#assertions-about-expected-exceptions)

Comment: Thanks! So when I raise the exception I have to add some parameter, i.e., `raise SomeError('some error message')`?

Comment: @Mihai see now answer to understand.

Comment: Do you know why PyCharm attentions me like this: Expected type 'TypeVar('T')', got 'Type[SomeError]' instead?

Comment: Shouldn't the `assert` be outside the `with` block?

Comment: @simanacci is correct, `assert` should be in line with the `with` block, not inside it (silly Python and your indentation)